# Implementing a Chain of Validations with their own confirmation dialogs?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I need to perform a series of validations, say ValidationA, ValidationB, ValidationC.

If any validation fails, the chain fails to validate immediately.

Each subsequent validation is performed only after the previous validation condition passes.

If a validation condition fails, I need to show a confirmation dialog to the user, e.g. "Are you sure you want to do this?" — where if the user says "Yes" then we should move on to the next validation in the chain. If the user says "No" in the confirmation dialog, then we can fail immediately.

What is a good way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe it's time to mark an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in C#, but I hope it's clear. The most important thing here is that raw validation is separated from the UI. OverridableValidator is an "UI guy" which gets "logic guy" in constructor, along with the message to be shown to the user.

```
interface IValidator<T>
{
    bool IsValid(T subject);
}

class OverridableValidator<T> : IValidator<T>
{
    readonly IValidator<T> _validator;
    readonly string _confirmOverrideMessage;

    public OverridableValidator(IValidator<T> validator, string confirmOverrideMessage)
    {
        _validator = validator;
        _confirmOverrideMessage = confirmOverrideMessage;
    }

    public bool IsValid(T subject)
    {
        if (_validator.IsValid(subject))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return MessageBox.Show(_confirmOverrideMessage, "Confirmation required", MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public int HeightInCentimeters {get;set;}
}

class MaturityValidator : IValidator<Person>
{
    public bool IsValid(Person guy)
    {
        return guy.Age >= 18;
    }
}

class HeightValidator : IValidator<Person>
{
    public bool IsValid(Person guy)
    {
        return guy.HeightInCentimeters < 120;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var ageValidator = new OverridableValidator<Person>(new MaturityValidator(), "Do you want to sell him cigarettes?");
    var heightValidator = new OverridableValidator<Person>(new HeightValidator(), "Do you want to invite such a short person to your basketball team?");

    var validatedPerson = new Person() { Age = 15, HeightInCentimeters = 140 };
    var validatorsList = new[] {ageValidator, heightValidator};
    foreach (var validator in validatorsList)
    {
        if (!validator.IsValid(validatedPerson))
        {
            return; //validaton failed
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("This guy can smoke and play in NBA");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement it like this:

```
(ValidationA || UserConfirmationA) && (ValidationB || UserConfirmationB) && (ValidationC || UserConfirmationC)
```

where Validation and UserComfirmation are function which do what their names say and return a boolean.

I assume that `&&` and `||` are lazy which is the case in most languages.

Comment: Poor design. I'm even afraid how the real code could look like... Spaghetti hell.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what dzendras said, it might help for you to look at [Chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) allowing you to add validators dynamically.